# Mongodb aggregation function in Amazon Document DB

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services

I have the following document in the mongodb running on amazon document DB, which is mongodb 3.6

```
{"item":"journal", "instock":[{"warehouse":"A", "qty":[2,4,5] }, {"warehouse":"C", "qty":[8,5,2] }, {"warehouse":"F", "qty":[3] }, {"warehouse":"K", "qty":[2,4,8] }, {"warehouse":"P", "qty":[3,7,9] } ] }
```

With this data I simply want to extract instock objects having a qty 5.
The query I'm running on my local mongodb(4.2) is the following:

```
db.inventory.aggregate({$match:{"item": "journal"}}, {$project:{instock: {$filter: {input: "$instock", cond: {$in: [5, "$$this.qty"] } } } }})
```

which gives the expected result:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f59a6bd85a366711c35fc7b"), "instock" : [ { "warehouse" : "A", "qty" : [ 2, 4, 5 ] }, { "warehouse" : "C", "qty" : [ 8, 5, 2 ] } ] }
```

But the problem is when I ran the same query in DocumentDB, if gives an error:
"errmsg" : "$in requires an array as a second argument, found: string",

As per the mongodb documentation, $filter operation is there since version 3.2. So I'm not quite sure what's the issue here. Any ideas please?

Answer (score 1):

I am looking into why this query is not working against Amazon DocumentDB. In the meanwhile, here is a rewritten query that works on Amazon DocumentDB and should do what your original query is trying to do :

#### Insert Documents

```
db.coll.insert({
    "item": "journal",
    "instock": [{
        "warehouse": "A",
        "qty": [2, 4, 5]
    }, {
        "warehouse": "C",
        "qty": [8, 5, 2]
    }, {
        "warehouse": "F",
        "qty": [3]
    }, {
        "warehouse": "K",
        "qty": [2, 4, 8]
    }, {
        "warehouse": "P",
        "qty": [3, 7, 9]
    }]
});
```

#### Query

```
db.coll.aggregate([
    { $match: { "item": "journal" } }, 
    { $unwind: "$instock" }, 
    { $match: { "instock.qty": 5 } }, 
    {
    "$group": {
        "_id": { "id": "$id", "item": "$item" },
        "instock": {
            "$push": {
                "warehouse": "$instock.warehouse",
                "qty": "$instock.qty"
            }
        }
    }
}]).pretty()
```

#### Output

```
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "item" : "journal"
    }, 
    "instock" : [
        {
            "warehouse" : "A", 
            "qty" : [
                2.0, 
                4.0, 
                5.0
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "warehouse" : "C", 
            "qty" : [
                8.0, 
                5.0, 
                2.0
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```